# How to fetch all values for a single key from Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch all the names from my `PeopleName` class from Parse. It's not showing any build error, but I get a runtime error `Error: field Name cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object (Code: 102, Version: 1.2.17)`.

Here is code. Any help?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PeopleNames"];
     [query includeKey:@"Name"];
     [query selectKeys:@[@"Name"]];
     [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

     for (PFObject *object in results) {
        [self.boyNames addObject:[object objectForKey:@"Name"]];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[query selectKeys:@[@"Name"]];` is correct to limit the returned data to only the names. `[query includeKey:@"Name"];` is not required as it is the way to include the destination objects at the other end of a relationship (which you don't have).

So, keep `[query selectKeys:@[@"Name"]];` and remove `[query includeKey:@"Name"];` and you'll get what you want.

Comment: The error is gone, but I still not able to get the names in my self.boyNames NSMutable array. Would you mind helping me getting all the names in this array.

Comment: Have you logged the objects in the `results`? Also, log the `error`. What are they?

Comment: I am not getting any error. What I want to do is get all the names from the name column and add them to self.boyNames array by using [self.boyNames addObject:[object objectForKey:@"Name"]];

Comment: I added a log message here using     NSLog(@"names are %@", self.boyNames); and the result is [15047:a0b] names are (null)

Comment: Log `results` or the `object` in each iteration of the loop - what does it contain...

Comment: It also has serverData with both Key and Value.

Comment: What is `serverData`? We're interested in what keys and values the objects have. I assume that they all have `Name` set in the database?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the log.https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmofyauaae99i16/Screenshot%202013-12-15%2013.04.52.png

Comment: So the data coming back from Parse.com is fine. The problem is you never create the `self.boyNames` array so there is nothing to add the names to...

Comment: I have created boyNames as NSMutable array in my header file.

Comment: I created another array and it is working. Could you explain why this is was not adding to self.boyNames?

Comment: You didn't create another array, you instantiated one array so you can add the names to it. In the header file you only define the instance variable, no instance is created there (alloc init).

Comment: I am sorry guys. I am trying to understand this code but i can't understand if it will return a List of objects or a List of values of the key Name (List of names).

Comment: Can you help me with it. I am facing same problem in android. I need to get a List of all the values of a key (Name) of a class. This is the only place i can find with similar problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question, show what code you have and what results you get. Are you just setting `[query selectKeys:@[@"Name"]];` on your query? @VipulKumar

Comment: Yes I am. But in my understanding it will return "a list of ParseObjects" (instead of a list of Names) having the field "Name" in them. In this way, I will have to get "Name" of every Parse user by NSString *playerName = gameScore[@"Name"];. Is it right?

Comment: @VipulKumar Yes. Not sure if the Android SDK can help with that. Alternative is to use the REST API and process the JSON into a simple array of strings.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I should probably use REST. because in this way, i will have to make a lot of unnecessary requests.